# jQuery load ...execute parent js

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, load

I have a PHP query that displays the first 30 documents, then an anhor which loads the rest of the documents using jQuery load.

Although, the parent uses javascript for some effects. Although once loaded onto the document it doesn't seem to inherit it's script tags.

is there any solution for this?

Comment: What are the "documents" you're talking about? How about the parent? How do you mean it doesn't "inherit" its script tags? Whose script tags aren't getting inherited by who?

Answer (score 0):

you have to put your "effects" into a function, then in the success of the `load` you have to call that function again.

```
function effects(){
     //all your effects
}
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
   effects();
});
```